# ng-click directive not working on button

Tags: angularjs

**html**

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="tasks.passivate()">
            Passivate <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-if="tasks.passivating"></i>
    </button>
```

**task.controller**

```
 function passivate() {  
        console.log('passivate');
        vm.passivating = true;          
     return taskService
        .passivate(vm.task.id)
        .then(function (task) {
         vm.passivating = false;
        })
        .catch(alertError);
    }
```

The button does not work, `passivate` does not appear in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When referencing something from the *controller* in the *view*, you have to use the **`$scope`**. Your function definition should be:

```
$scope.tasks.passivate = function() {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your button, I believe is part of the view which is now bound to a controller. The controller creates a scope object which actually glues your view and the controller. So if you want to invoke a function from the view it should have the scope reference. Hence $scope should be used:-

```
$scope.tasks.passivate = function(){

    //----your logic goes here.
}
```

Its good to see that you are using tasks.passivate as it will save your from prototypal inheritance. To know more:- [Click here](https://medium.com/@fay_jai/understanding-prototypal-inheritance-in-angulars-scope-638c6faabd5b)